# Comparing integers from a text file and program that has strings involved

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I've tried in vain to compare scores in my application with scores already saved in a separate text file. Comparing the score is easy enough when strings aren't involved but when I save the score and assign it a name, the program doesn't work as it cannot parse strings & integers.

Example text file:

```
Name, 8
Name, 1
Name, 4
```

Code I'm using to compare:

```
        int highScore = 0;
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null)                  
        {
            try {
                int score = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());   
                if (score > highScore)                       
                { 
                    highScore = score; 
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                //ignore invalid scores
                //System.err.println("ignoring invalid score: " + line);
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
    }
```

The rest of the code is fine and the score is generated as the game finishes comparing it to the score in the file, it just generates a 0 value when comparing as it reads the string and doesn't work. I'm not sure on how to use scanners/delimiters.

EDIT:
I'd like the program to execute and show the name of the user which got that highscore. So the desired output would be;

```
The all time high score was 8 by Name1
```

Currently it only says the highscore (following Michu93's input).

Answer (score 0):

Remove digits from string and parse it to int:

```
int score = Integer.valueOf(line.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

@Edit

```
int highScore = 0;
String name = "";
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        try {
            int score = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[1]); 
            if (score > highScore) { 
                highScore = score; 
                name = line.split(" ")[0].replace(",", "");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            //ignore invalid scores
            //System.err.println("ignoring invalid score: " + line);
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("The all time high score was %s by %s", highscore, name));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("ERROR");
} finally {
    reader.close(); // close stream always in finnaly block or use try with resources!!!
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps but I also want to print out the name of the player which got the high score. This only prints the top high score. I guess I wasn't clear.

Comment: @j.hashi21 check it now.

Ok, I got it wrong. If you also need name then I would make a variable 'String name;' and when `score` is higher than `highscore` then assign this name to `name`

Answer (score 0):

Run the below program. It will give you desired output. Please correct the other things, I just concentrated on output.

```
    public class Test {
    static int highScore = 0;
    static String highscorer = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/com/test/package1/txt.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    String[] parts = line.split(",");
                    int tempScore = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
                    String tempHigScorer = (parts[0]);
                    if (tempScore > highScore) {
                        highScore = tempScore;
                        highscorer = tempHigScorer;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                    // handle NumberFormatException if any
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("ERROR");
        }
        System.out.println("The all time high score was " + highScore + " by name " + highscorer);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have put my txt.txt at location src/com/test/p  ackage1/txt.txt. you need to change this location. Is this solution working for you?

Comment: No, it keeps throwing a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 error :/
Maybe it's because I run the main method in a different class? It calls this method and executes it.

Comment: Is your text file contain data exactly in format name, 8    then a next new line.

Answer (score -1):

Observe that when you read a whole line you are getting a `String` with both Name and the `Integer` you want to get. I'd do the following:

```
int highScore = 0;
String name = "";
try {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("txt.txt"));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       try {
           String[] parts = line.split(",");
           if(parts.length > 1){
             int score = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
             if (score > highScore) {
                highScore = score;
                name = line[0];
             }
           }
       } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        //ignore invalid scores
        //System.err.println("ignoring invalid score: " + line);
      }
   }
   System.out.println("The all time high score was %s by %s", highScore, name);
   reader.close();
```

Comment: This throws a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" error at me.

Comment: @j.hashi21 I am at cel phone at this moment, so I can't run now, but probably some line is blank, or doesn't have a  ",", so you need to verify the "parts" length to verify if is possible to get parts[1] and, if possible, then you convert it to integer

Comment: Not without another catch/finally expression

Comment: I just added IOException maybe because my method didn't have any throws, I think.